# VSS6.0c Invalid syntax

Tags: visual-sourcesafe

Opening as admin and I get an invalid syntax on line 42 of the ini file.

"Too many environment strings" Then line 47 and other lines until it opens.
Any ideas as to why this may be happening?

Nothing appears out of the ordinary with the ini file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the solution in this kb article and see if it solves your problem:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/159777/en-us